# Mapping cone and quotient of homotopy groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I'm wondering if we can describe the effect of quotienting by some subgroup of a homotopy group by actually replacing the space with the mapping cone of the generators of the subgroups.

To be more precise, take $X$ say a $CW$-complex and $\phi$ some map $\mathbb{S}^k\to X$ representing a non zero element in $\pi_k(X)$.

If you look at $cone(\phi)$ then certainly you obtain a surjective map $j_\star:\pi_k(X)\to \pi_k(cone(\phi))$ given by the fact that $(cone(\phi),X)$ is $k$-connected, and of course almost by definition $j_\star[\phi]=0$.
However this is not sufficient to conclude that $\pi_k(cone(\phi))=\pi_k(X)/<\phi>$ and i have the feeling that it won't be true in general.

Am I missing something here? Is there an example when $\pi_k$ of the cone will actually be smaller than the quotient by the subgroup generated by the map?

Edit: Here is a proof that it actually works when $X$ is $1$-connected.

If $X$ is one connected, as $(cone(\phi), X)$ is $k$-connected we know, by homotopy excision, that $\pi_j(cone(\phi), X)\to \pi_j(cone(\phi)/ X, \star)$ is an isomorphism for $j=2,...,k+1$. But $cone(\phi)/ X\simeq \mathbb{S}^{k+1}$ and thus $\pi_{k+1}(cone(\phi), X)=\mathbb{Z}$ and is generated by $\phi$.
We thus get an exact sequence $$\mathbb{Z}\to \pi_k(cone(\phi))\to \pi_k(X)\to 0$$ where the left map maps $1$ to $[\phi]$ giving us the desire isomorphism.

So now all that is left is finding a counter example when $X$ isn't $1$-connected, but I have the feeling that it shouldn't be too complicated.

Comment: I think this is in Hatcher. You quotient by the smallest subgroup containing $\phi$ closed under the action of the fundamental group.

Comment: I'll take a look in Hatcher, I don't really remember this result. So that means that this result will be true, provided $X$ is simply connected... maybe I can derive this from homotopy excision.

Comment: My thought is that it should follow from a relative Hurewicz argument. I will keep my eye out for a reference.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Ok, it does work with homotopy excision when $X$ is $1$-connected (see my edit). I'll try and find a counter example in the case non simply connected, but the proof already gives a hint as to what to look for, namely an element that is killed by the map $\pi_{k+1}(cone(\phi), X)\to \pi_{k+1}(\mathbb{S}^{k+1})$ should give us an $\alpha$ in the kernel of $\pi_k(X)\to \pi_k(cone(\phi))$ that is not in the subgroup generated by $\phi$.

Comment: If you'd like to type up an answer you should do that, otherwise check out proposition 3.30 of Ranicki's "Algebraic and Geometric Surgery" (page 44 in my edition).

Comment: The key word is [Blakers-Massey](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Blakers-Massey+theorem). In dimension $1$ you have van Kampen.